# pyqt5 How to get the current file and switch to the next one, one button can correspond to multiple events。

Tags: pyqt5

[image]

I want to switch to the next item by clicking on the item in the list and then clicking next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect the button to this function and pass the items list :

```
def click(list):
     item=list.selectedItems()[0]
     file_name=item.text()
     #get the file with file name

     row = self.selectedIndexes()[0].row()
     item.setSelected(False)
     next_item= list.item(row+1)
     if next_item is not None:
         next_item.setSelected(True)
```